# I can't focus to first item on gridview when I did on talkback on Android application

Tags: android, gridview, android-gridview, talkback

I build an Android application. But I have a littile problem.

This is Talk-back problem.

If I did on talkback that I can' focus move to first item on gridview.

I did set grid item height at getvView. If I remove set grid item height that I can move to focus first item on gridview.

1. I want to resize gridview item height.
2. But if I did that I can't move to focus first item on gridview.

[image]

[image]

please help me.

Comment: Need code to help

Comment: @santoshkumar I uploaded it. sorrry, I can't upload source because I can't use internet ony PC.

Comment: can you add app screenshot too

Comment: I did it. I can't full capture about my application

Comment: @santoshkumar I can touch and click and longclick about first item on gridview. This is only talkback problem.

Comment: I am still not clear what is your issue

Comment: I can't focus move to first item when I turned on talkback.